# Can we control ViewEncapsulation.None from affecting the other components in the angular application?

Tags: angular, angular8

```
@Component({
...
...
...
encapsulations: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

when i use **encapsulation** like that it conflicts the default style in the other components in application.

Comment: did you try ViewEncapsulation.Native and ViewEncapsulation.Emulated?

Comment: Yes I tried this but it does not works out for me. Thanks

Comment: Can u elaborate?

Comment: Actually I have created a component where I need to override the angular-material default style. So as per doc's of angular material I came to know that if I put **encapsulations: ViewEncapsulation.None** in the components metadata part we can apply the style of our own. That is what I did and I became able to apply my own CSS code in the angular material design but the thing is that I affects the other components style because **encapsulations: ViewEncapsulation.None** effects the other defaults style of the other components that as per doc. @pritesh

Answer (score 3):

When you load a component with ViewEncapsulation.None, its styles are applied to all the app.

**So the answer is no, you can't...**

**But**, what you can do is writing unique css style in your components style file, for example:

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
```

in your *toolbar html* you have something like:

```
<span>hello</span>
<div>My name is</div>
```

to apply styles only to this component write in *its styles file*:

```
app-toolbar span{
  color: green;
}

app-toolbar div{
  color: red;
}
```

or even better if you use scss files:

```
app-toolbar {
  span {
    color: green;
  }
  div {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

What you also could do and this works for sure (tested):

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
```

In this component html file (wrap all of its content in a div):

```
<div class="my-toolbar">
  <span>hello</span>
  <div>My name is</div>
</div>
```

Then in its style file:

```
.my-toolbar span{
  color: green;
}

.my-toolbar div{
  color: red;
}
```

or in scss format:

```
.my-toolbar {
  span {
    color: green;
  }
  div {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Showy, Thanks for the answer, though it does not works for me yet I learnt something from you. @Showy

Comment: @RajeshMalakar Check out my edit and let me know, best regards

Comment: This works 100%, but in my case I wanted to change something in angular material design (I wanted to hide default scrollbar of the **tab navigation** body which I am able to do but it implicitly conflicts other component's design). I appreciate your response. Thanks for the answer @Showy.

Answer (score 0):

For override the angular-material default style you can use **ng-deep** in your scss file instead of using **encapsulations: ViewEncapsulation.None** in your ts file.

For example:

Overriding angular tooltip:

**my-tooltip.component.ts**

```
...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './my-tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-tooltip.component.scss']
})

...
```

**my-tooltip.componnent.html**

```
<button
   matTooltip="tooltip text here"
   matTooltipPosition="after"
   matTooltipClass="my-tooltip-class">
</button>
```

**my-tooltip.componnent.scss**

```
::ng-deep .my-tooltip-class {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: small;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```